# how to find user ids of all commenters in a post

Tags: posts, comments, users

Is there a function in wordpress that grabs all the users(user ids) who have commented on a post? I have the post id available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get_comments() answer by Poulomi Nag is correct. This will be somewhat more efficient.

```
global $wpdb, $post;
$query = sprintf("SELECT user_id
                    FROM {$wpdb->comments}
                    JOIN {$wpdb->posts} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->comments}.comment_post_ID
                    WHERE comment_post_ID = %d
                    AND comment_approved = '1'",
                  $post->ID);
$authors = $wpdb->get_col($query);
$authors = array_unique($authors);
$authors = array_diff($authors,array('0')); // Remove those where users are not registered
```

Another alternative is to use WP_Comment_Query
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2/wp-includes/comment.php#L186

Comment: Aside from taht this isn't really a secure way of doing it `sprintf/$wpdb->prepare`, in which way is it "more efficient"? Please elaborate. And btw: `get_comments()` calls `WP_Comment_Query` internally.

Comment: I think the sprintf should be more efficient for this case.
$wpdb->prepare does some internal security checks which are only needed if the ID comes from user input(bad code if it does)

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet is one way of doing it:

```
$args = array(
'status' => 'approve',
'post_id' => get_the_ID()
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
foreach( $comments as $comment )
    echo $comment->user_id;
```

The user IDs of course should be used for better use than just `echo`ing.